Trigger a sound when a form is submitted to spreadsheet
I have a google form for patrons to submit print requests and the spreadsheet of submissions is open on a laptop for all student staff to use in the office area.  Multiple student staff throughout the day need to access and print the different items that have come in.  I don't want to set up email notifications to each student staff email.  Instead, I would like the laptop to make a sound alert when a new submission comes in, each time the form is submitted.
Is this possible?  I've looked at some other posts regarding sound, but it tends to be for other reasons, and I am not knowledgable enough to figure out how to change it to meet this need.
Thank you in advance for any and all assistance.
